# Not able to use *p1 / *p2 as it's considering /* as start of comment section

Tags: c++, syntax, escaping

The code below looks okay, but when I tried to execute the code, at the `k = *p1/*p2;` line, the `/*` is taken as the start of a comment. How can I avoid this?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n1=10,n2=2,k,*p1,*p2;
  p1=&n1,p2=&n2;
  k=*p1/*p2;
  cout<<k; return 0;
}
```

I tried to place `//*` instead of `/*` and all other escape characters but it did not work.

Are there any escape characters like in Unix - `sed -e 's/\./\. /g' -e 's/_/_ /g'`?

Comment: What about adding a space in between? Your code would benefit from spaces here and there... and they are not expensive either

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use parenthesis:

```
k = (*p1)/(*p2);
```

or more spacing:

```
k = *p1 / *p2;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a good idea in general to separate operands and operators with spaces. So instead of

```
  int n1=10,n2=2,k,*p1,*p2;
  p1=&n1,p2=&n2;
  k=*p1/*p2;
```

I would write

```
  int n1 = 10, n2 = 2, k, *p1, *p2;
  p1 = &n1, p2 = &n2;
  k = *p1 / *p2;
```

In this case not only such curious things can be avoided but the code is also more readable.